# Finding the greatest power of $2$ less than or equal to a given number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, binary, perfect-powers

> I'm looking for an algorithm, or better yet formula, that I can use with a piece of paper and a pen to find the greatest power of $2$ less than or equal to a given number.

Suppose I have the number $15285$, what's the easiest way to find out what the greatest integer power of $2$ that is less than or equal to that number without using a calculator? For example, for the number $9$, the maximum power of $2$ is $3$, because $2^4>9\geq 2^3$

Comment: $2^{13}$ is a bit over $8000$.

Comment: 'less than', or 'less than or equal to'?

Comment: @barto, less than or equal to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following method is essentially [binary expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), discarding some information along the way.

If $n$ is even, divide by $2$;
If $n$ is odd, subtract $1$ and divide by $2$.
Repeat until you get $1$.

The number of steps is the exponent you are looking for.

**Examples**
$n=9$: $\to4\to2\to1$, three steps
$n=15$: $\to7\to3\to1$, three steps
$n=16$: $\to8\to4\to2\to1$, four steps
$n=15285$: $\to7642\to3821\to1910\to955\to477\to238\to119\to59\to29\to14\to7\to3\to1$, 13 steps

Using a calculator, one can do $\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor$ (or just take $\log_2n$ and ignore the fractional part).

Comment: thanks, so there is no formula to find that number without going through these long steps?

Comment: There is, but not so easy to compute without a calculator.

Comment: The formula is $\lfloor \log_2 x \rfloor$.  and $\log_2 x$ can be found by $\ln x/\ln 2$.  A rule of thumb is $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 1000 = 10^3$ so count the digits and divide by 3.  The power will be slightly higher.

Comment: @fleablood, thanks, can you please expand it into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just divide by 2, ignore remainder, repeat.

But as $x = 2^{\log_2 x}$ and $2^{10} = 1024 \approx 10^3$ a way of guessing could be $\log_2 x \approx \frac 13 \log_{10} x$:

Well, I'll show with an example:

$23,536,286,290$

$23,536,286,290 \approx 2.3 * 10^{10} = 23 * 10^{9}$

$= 23 * 1000^3 < 23 * 1024^3 = 23 * 2^{30}$

$2^4 < 23 < 2^5$

So the power should be about $34$ maybe less.  Less than $35$.

To determine if that is so:

So $2^{30} = 1024^3 = 1,000,000,000 + 3*24*1000,000 + 3*24^2*1000 + 24^3$

$\approx 1,072,xxx,xxx$.  So $2^{34} \approx 16* 1,072,xxx,xxx \approx 1,7xx,xxx,xxx < 23,536,286,290 < 2*1,7xx,xxx,xxx \approx 3,4xx,xxx,xxx \approx 2^{35}$ so the answer *is* $2^{34}$.

====

Actually to make the above answer clearer:

$xyzabcde$ has $n + 1$ digits.  Write as $x.y * 10^n$.  Try to eyeball $x.y = 2^k$  The highest power is *about* $n*10/3 + k$

Double check by writing as $xy * 10^{n- 1}$.  Try to eyball $xy = w^j$.  The highest power is *about* $(n-1)*10/3 + j$.

Choose the for which eyeballing $x.y = 2^k$ or $xy = 2^j$ seem to have less range of error.

Comment: thanks a lot, I upvoted :)

Comment: Taking the log of 10 and dividing by three and multiplying by 10 will always be a little high as 1024 > 1000.  It seem to be at about 2^{35} or 10^{11} the descrepancy becomes significant to a power.  So maybe a second rule should subtract a power for every 11 digits in the original.

Comment: thanks, I'll think through your last comment

Answer (score 1):

Building off the answer of @fleablood, what you can do *easily* with pen and paper is going to depend on what is written on your paper ... or your memory :-)

- write your number with commas (or separator): 15285-> 15,285
- find the largest powers of 2 less than or equal to the first group: 2^3 = 8 < 15 < 16 = 2^4; this requires that you know, can do or have written the sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024 for powers of 2 from 0 through 10.
- the largest power of 2 in 10^(3*g) is 2^(10*g - 1) -- if there are less than 30 groups of digits after the first [*]. So for a single group after the first the largest power is 2^9
- add the exponents (3 + 9 = 12). The actual value will be this or 1 larger (to account for the possibility of rounding) so in this case that actual value is predicted to be [12, 13] and the actual value is 13.

As another example, consider 3,141,592,653,589. The leading group (3) is larger than 2^1 but less than 2^2; there are 4 additional groups (g = 4); the lower estimate is 1 + 39 = 40 so the actual should be 40 or 41 -- it's 41 in this case and the true value is 41.51....

[*] There is no *simple* way to get a *quick, exact* value but if (on your paper) you have the precomputed values at which k in 10^(3*g) ~= 2^(10*g - k) increases you can handle more than 30 groups after the first. For g in the range of 1 through 29, k is 1. Starting at 30 groups, k is 2. And at 59 it is 3. There is no *simple* pattern to this, however; the values of g at which k increase by 1 are 30 (k=2), 59, 88, 117, 147, 176, 205, 234, 264 (k=10), 293, 322, 351, 380, 410, 439, 468, 497, 527, 556 (k=20), 585, 614, 643, 673, 702, 731, 760, 790, 819, 848 (k=30), 877, 907 (k=32), ...]

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking divisibility, your number is odd so the only power of two that divides into this number is $1$. The thing is that this is a boring answer, but it's the only one.

But if we're talking about the largest power of two smaller than this number, I usually do this by brute force. Try factoring the number and obtain some estimates with powers of two.

Comment: largest power of two that goes into an odd number is 0, not 1

Comment: One is a power of two: $2^0 = 1$. I don't refer to the numbers here by their powers, just by their values.

Answer (score 0):

Floor ( logarithm to the base 2 of the given number).

Comment: Do you know how to find log base 2 without a calculator?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/663884)

Comment: By dividing by 2 repeatedly, until a quotient < 4 is reached, and keeping track of the number of divisions.

@Babai, what critical ingredient of an answer did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Many calculators can give you the answer for a given number $n$ the following way:

Example:$$\log_2(77869)=16.2487614787$$Therefore the answer in this case is $16$; in fact,

$$2^{16}=65536\lt77869\lt2^{17}=131072$$